# heroku server 500 error after a git push it works locally though

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, deployment

I did a git push and then all of a sudden my app responds with a server error. I have been trying to get my my scheduler to work it works fine locally. It gave me a problem but I fixed it using a git pull request. it was working fine locally and then all of sudden server error 500. I did heroku logs and got this response

my procfile

```
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery -A blog worker -B -l info
```

my requirements.txt

```
    amqp==1.4.9
    anyjson==0.3.3
    attrs==16.2.0
    beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
    billiard==3.3.0.23
    celery==3.1.23
    cffi==1.8.3
    click==6.6
    cryptography==1.5
    cssselect==0.9.2
    decorator==4.0.10
    dj-database-url==0.4.0
    Django==1.10.1
    django-bootstrap-pagination==1.6.2
    django-celery==3.1.17
    django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
    django-dynamic-scraper==0.11.2
    django-haystack==2.4.1
    django-markdown-deux==1.0.5
    django-pagedown==0.1.1
    django-redis-cache==1.6.5
    django-taggit==0.18.1
    feedparser==5.2.1
    future==0.15.2
    gunicorn==19.4.5
    html5lib==0.9999999
    httplib2==0.9.2
    idna==2.1
    jsonpath-rw==1.4.0
    kombu==3.0.35
    lxml==3.6.4
    markdown2==2.3.1
    oauth2client==2.2.0
    oauthlib==1.1.2
    parsel==1.0.3
    Pillow==3.2.0
    ply==3.8
    psycopg2==2.6.1
    pyasn1==0.1.9
    pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
    pycparser==2.14
    PyDispatcher==2.0.5
    pyOpenSSL==16.1.0
    pytz==2016.6.1
    queuelib==1.4.2
    redis==2.10.5
    requests==2.9.1
    requests-oauthlib==0.6.1
    rsa==3.4.2
    Scrapy==1.1.2
    scrapy-djangoitem==1.1.1
    scrapyd==1.1.0
    service-identity==16.0.0
    simplejson==3.8.2
    six==1.10.0
    tweepy==3.5.0
    Twisted==16.4.1
    uritemplate==0.6
    w3lib==1.15.0
    whitenoise==3.0
    Whoosh==2.7.4
    zope.interface==4.3.2
```

this all works locally though

I have scaled my web and worker to zero and started them back up still nothin. I have not seen any L,H,R error codes

EDIT

this part of my output

```
 2016-09-24T02:23:53.832216+00:00 app[worker.1]:
```

its red, this color just started happening. Earlier in the day I had using django celery beat locally I get error 'PeriodicTask' object has no attribute '_default_manager' and I fixed it following a pul request

```
obj = self.model._default_manager.get(pk=self.model.pk)
```

turned to

```
98  Model = type(self.model)
99  obj = Model._default_manager.get(pk=self.model.pk)
```

## EDIT

set my production DEBUG to True so I could see if I could see something. And it said

```
ImportError: No module named 'django.core.context_processors'
```

this was not in my heroku logs and as i mentioned before this works locally. I believe this is called failing silently. gonna see if I can figure this out. If someone has any idea what's going on and how to fix this, let me know. Right now google is my friend.

Comment: Post your `Procfile` and your `requirements.txt` as well.

Comment: @Lucas I just posted it.

Comment: Hmm i was sure it was the issue i had, where i wasn't including gunicorn in my requirements, but you're including it in yours. I dug into the error at the top of the file a bit and it seems to be related to Go. Have you installed the latest version of Go on your heroku instance?

Comment: you mean redis to go?

Comment: I pip install --upgrade redis and it's the latest

Comment: For whatever reason, your `REDIS_URL` is not being set. See here: `BROKER_URL = os.environ['REDIS_URL']`. Make sure that is properly being set on the production server. That will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying I fixed that and it still isn't working. that error went away. matter of fact there are none. The only thing I can say is that the app[worker.1]: etc is in red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your local Django version is earlier then in requirements.txt, because in Django 1.8 [built-in template context processors have been moved to django.template.context_processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#django-core-context-processors).

Try this example settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```